# Is one Jewish life worth more than multiple non-Jewish (Arab) lives

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Doing a project for a class called Rendering Legal Decisions. Please let me know if you have an answer using specific Halacha

Comment: How do you measure the "worth" of a life?

Comment: "Is one Jewish life worth more than multiple non-Jewish (Arab) lives" Worth in terms of what? What is the context?

Comment: Just to reiterate: this was closed because the question is far too general, and lacking in context. Please update it because it sounds like it could be interesting, if only we knew what you meant!

Answer (score 1):

No. Jewish lives are not worth more than anyone else's lives.

"According to Rabbi Yoḥanan quoting Rabbi Shimon ben Yehotzadak there are only three mitzvot that are so severe that a person should give up his life rather than perform the forbidden acts. Those mitzvot are:

```
avoda zara (idol worship)
gilui arayot (forbidden sexual relations)
shefikhut damim (murder)
```

The Gemara presents Biblical passages as the source for this rule regarding Avoda Zara and Gilui Arayot. When it comes to Shefikhut Damim the Gemara argues that no proof-text is necessary, as it is a sevara – a logical argument – that murder cannot be permitted to save a life. To illustrate the sevara, the Gemara tells of a person who approached Rabba with the following question:

“The ruler of my village came to me and said ‘kill that person, and if you do not then I will kill you.’ Can I follow his order so that I will be able to save myself?”

Rabba responded:

“Allow yourself to be killed, but you may not kill another. Who says that your blood is redder than his? Perhaps his blood is redder than yours.”

On a simple level, Rabba’s argument is that we cannot tell whose life is more valuable, so we will not allow you to save your life at the expense of another.

Rabbeinu Yehonatan explains Rabba’s answer by arguing that really the laws of the Torah are so important that we would not allow them to be “pushed aside” even at the expense of human life. The reason the halakha permits someone to transgress a serious prohibition – like Shabbat – in order to save a life is because we weigh that single ḥillul Shabbat (desecration of Shabbat) against the potential Shabbatot that the person will observe in the course of his lifetime. In our case the argument is that we cannot possibly know “whose blood is redder” i.e. who will live longer and perform more mitzvot."

Source: https://steinsaltz.org/daf/sanhedrin74/

Answer (score -2):

In what context? If we are talking about the current situation in Israel, then yes, most definitely, it is allowed since it's a defensive war, which is a milchemet mitzvah against a "nation" that doesn't want peace. According to the Rambam [Melachim uMilchamot - Chapter 6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188350/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-6.htm)

> ד וְאִם לֹא הִשְׁלִימוּ אוֹ שֶׁהִשְׁלִימוּ וְלֹא קִבְּלוּ שֶׁבַע
> מִצְוֹת. עוֹשִׂין עִמָּהֶם מִלְחָמָה וְהוֹרְגִין כָּל הַזְּכָרִים
> הַגְּדוֹלִים. וּבוֹזְזִין כָּל מָמוֹנָם וְטַפָּם. וְאֵין הוֹרְגִין
> אִשָּׁה וְלֹא קָטָן שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים כ, יד) "וְהַנָּשִׁים וְהַטָּף"
> זֶה טַף שֶׁל זְכָרִים. בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים בְּמִלְחֶמֶת
> הָרְשׁוּת שֶׁהוּא עִם שְׁאָר הָאֻמּוֹת. אֲבָל שִׁבְעָה עֲמָמִין
> וַעֲמָלֵק שֶׁלֹּא הִשְׁלִימוּ אֵין מַנִּיחִין מֵהֶם נְשָׁמָה
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים כ, טו) "כֵּן תַּעֲשֶׂה לְכָל" וְגוֹ' (דברים כ, טז)
> "רַק מֵעָרֵי הָעַמִּים" (דברים כ, טז) "לֹא תְחַיֶּה כָּל נְשָׁמָה".
> וְכֵן הוּא אוֹמֵר בַּעֲמָלֵק (דברים כה, יט) "תִּמְחֶה אֶת זֵכֶר
> עֲמָלֵק". וּמִנַּיִן שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְדַבֵּר אֶלָּא בְּאֵלּוּ שֶׁלֹּא
> הִשְׁלִימוּ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (יהושע יא, יט) "לֹא הָיְתָה עִיר אֲשֶׁר
> הִשְׁלִימָה אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל בִּלְתִּי הַחִוִּי ישְׁבֵי גִבְעוֹן
> אֶת הַכּל לָקְחוּ בַמִּלְחָמָה" (יהושע יא, כ) "כִּי מֵאֵת ה' הָיְתָה
> לְחַזֵּק אֶת לִבָּם לִקְרַאת הַמִּלְחָמָה אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל לְמַעַן
> הַחֲרִימָם". מִכְלַל שֶׁשָּׁלְחוּ לָהֶם לְשָׁלוֹם וְלֹא קִבְּלוּ:
>
> If they do not agree to a peaceful settlement, or if they agree to a
> peaceful settlement, but refuse to accept the seven mitzvot, war
> should be waged against them.
>
> All males past majority should be killed. Their money and their
> children should be taken as spoil, but neither women or children
> should be killed, as Deuteronomy 20:14 states: "But the women and the
> children... take as spoil." "The children" refer to males below the
> age of majority.
>
> The above applies to a milchemet hareshut fought with other nations.
> However, if either the seven nations or Amalek refuse to accept a
> peaceful settlement, not one soul of them may be left alive as ibid.
> 20:15-16 states: "Do this to all the cities that ... are not the
> cities of these nations. However, from the cities of these nations,...
> do not leave a soul alive." Similarly, in regard to Amalek,
> Deuteronomy 25:19 states: "Obliterate the memory of Amalek."
>
> How do we know that these commands are only referring to those who did
> not accept a peaceful settlement? Joshua 11:19-20 states: "There was
> no city which accepted a peaceful settlement with the children of
> Israel except the Chivites who lived in Gibeon. All the rest, they
> conquered in battle. This was inspired by God, Who strengthened their
> hearts to engage in battle against Israel so that they would be
> destroyed." From these statements, we can infer that a peaceful
> settlement was offered, but they did not accept it.

Comment: what is "allowed"?

Comment: Allowed as in actively or passively letting someone die (killing the aggressors) to save the life of a single jew, even if it is extremely disproportionate.